# What is the difference between echoing strings to a file and pasting to it?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, diff

Today I tried to add Virtualbox repo to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` via

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

however error occurs when I apt-get update:

> E: Malformed line 1 in source list
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (dist parse) E: The list of
>   sources could not be read.

It can't be wrong with the string, because if I copy/paste the repo string into a new list file, apt-get update works perfectly. I even try to diff two list file, and the result is even unexplainable:

```
diff VirtualBox.list virtualbox.list

1c1
< deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
---
> deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

As the result, diff shows line 1 has different, but where exactly is the different? I don't think it's to do with malformed issue, but have no idea why.

Please give me some idea or hints, many thanks!!

Comment: Use `cmp` to see which byte is different. Or `vimdiff` - that will highlight the differing regions.

Comment: > over writes the file, >> appends. Otherwise, not sure what you are asking.

Comment: many thanks for the debug clues and the much more clear title. Somehow I couldn't reproduce this issue, last night I copied the string from  my evernote, probably different new line char has been copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that one version has a newline at the end, where the other does not.  You would not notice unless you knew what to look for.

You may need to do it this way:

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib\n" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a "\n" always works. However it's my first time encountering this symptom, the failure string I copied was from evernote, for some reason i encountered this issue by copy from it.